# Do I need to refresh or restart anything after I add/update a crontab in Ubuntu Server 8.04?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-8.04

When you change something in Apache you need to reload or restart apache. Does anything need to be refreshed or restarted in Ubuntu Server 8.04 after I add/update the crontab? Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

No. As long as you use the `crontab -e` command to edit the file, when you save it, you'll get a 'New Crontab Installed' message. That's it.

Comment: The same applies to `crontab <filename>` -- and to `crontab -r`, for that matter.

Comment: But what if you did not use `crontab -e` to edit the file?

Comment: It should still work if you edited the file directly, assuming you had permissions to do so. It's still recommended to use the crontab command.

Comment: @user5359531 If you want to restart cron for whatever reason (which will force reloading of crontab files) see this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193788/restarting-cron-after-changing-crontab-file

Answer (score 9):

The usual thing is to use `crontab -e` to edit the tables. The changes will be applied when you exit the editor. Otherwise the rules for re-reading changed crontabs are in the `cron(8)` man page. They will be re-read eventually, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: The change is not applied when you only save the file.

Answer (score 7):

It's important that you elaborate on HOW/WHERE you are adding crons.  But I think the following addresses any situation.

Yes, `cron` needs to be made aware that you made changes, but no, you don't *necessarily* need to explicitly do anything to update it.

I'm paraphrasing the `cron` manual here for the short version:

As mentioned, `crontab -e`, the preferred method, will notify `cron` that something changed.

However, `cron` "wakes up" every minute to see if it has tasks for that minute. It also scans `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` and will reload any files with an updated 'mtime' (modified time, meaning the file contents must have been updated).

So theoretically, if you do nothing, `cron` will "wake up" and see you made changes to anything directly in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

But if you can, use `crontab -e`.  When you are done editing, it even gives you feedback that it was updated, it says:

```
    crontab: installing new crontab
```

Specifically, this means that it refreshed its copy in memory for the file you just edited via `crontab`.

Here's a quote from the manual CRON(8) :

```
    cron searches its spool area (/var/spool/cron/crontabs) for
    crontab files (which are named after accounts in /etc/passwd);
    crontabs found are loaded into memory.  Note that crontabs in this
    directory should not be accessed directly - the crontab command
    should be used to access and update them.
```